# How to remove category label margins of highchart?

Tags: highcharts, react-highcharts

[image]
I use string for x axis categories. and I want remove the margins of the first category and last category label to make them align to left/ right. is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Set `pointPlacement` property to `'on'`:

```
series: [{
  ...,
  pointPlacement: 'on'
}]
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/4796/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.pointPlacement